# Fast Load with Control character delimiter

Tags: teradata

I have a file with Control P character(DLE  data link escape) as delimiter,
I am using below command for setting the record type and delimiter
(^P is control V+ Control P). As of now everything is fine data is loading to table successfully. But when i use hexadecimal equivalent for Control P character which is 'x10'. The fast load script failing with Delimited Data Parsing error: Column
              length overflow(s) in row 1 for column 1

```
.SET RECORD vartext '^P';
```

Comment: Teradata hex literal format would be '10'xc not 'x10', though that usage is not documented for FastLoad. If you use TPT, there is a TextDelimiterHEX option for the Data Connector Operator (value is just the hex digits, no x).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried with delimiter '10'XC , now i'm getting Expected DISPLAY_ERRORS, NOSTOP or a valid delimiter after the VARTEXT keyword, Is it possible to represent delimiters in hexa decimal format in case of fastload.

Comment: FastLoad documentation states control characters (other than TAB) are not supported as delimiters, though as you discovered it may work if you enter the control character between the quotes. If you want to enter the value in hex, use TPT instead of FastLoad and specify `TextDelimiterHEX='10'`